# onStartListener available for an activity

Tags: android, observer-pattern

I have a series of activities, one of which is called `UserActivity`. What I'd like to do is have an object `ListenerObject`, that listens specifically for when `UserActivity` starts or stops. That is, I want `UserActivity.onStart()` to call `ListenerObject.onActivityStart()` (or some method named similarly).

I know that I can create an observer pattern set of classes to do this, but I'm wondering if there already exists such a framework within the Android API, and, more importantly, an accepted set of use patterns.

Comment: is ListenerObject a singleton?

Comment: That's a good question. I hadn't anticipated that it would be, but I suppose that it _could_ be a singleton - there's no reason that it can't....

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through Broadcasts:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

In a few ways...

1)  Have both activities receive and start from the same intent.

2)  have activity 1 launch a broadcast to activity 2.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure this will work. I perhaps wasn't completely clear - the second part of the pattern - the `ListenerObject` is not actually an activity. It's actually a construct designed to connect/disconnect to/from Google Play Services.

Comment: You can define a broadcast receiver which instantiates objects or calls methods of your object.  It doesn't actually have to be an activity. It's the android default way to do this sort of thing.  Read up on broadcast receivers a little bit you'll see that this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I should say - exactly what you're looking for if you don't want to set up the observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If ListenerObject makes sense as a static singleton you can just call the method on it during `onStart()` and `onStop()`:

```
MySingleton.getSharedInstance().onActivityStart();
```

which would save you some overhead of the other valid methods mentioned.

The Android devs mention static singletons in the context of lazy creation for speed and reduced memory usage quite a bit it seems so it seems like an accepted pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the required life cycle of the ListenerObject.
Seems like you want it to be around when the UserActivity isn't, but what about when you have none of your Activities on screen?

You could start a Service and then bind / unbind to it in your UserActivity's onStart / onStop. The service would likely stay alive whilst your app was in the background.

You could (un)bind to a service in all your Activities' onStart/Stop and provide an IBinder interface which asks would allow the service to ask the Activity if it is the UserAnctivity. The service would live whilst you navigate the app, but die once you put it in the background or go to another activity that doesn't bind to it (probably not what you want if you're doing something with G+ authentication / in app purchases etc).

You could (like others suggest) create a singleton, which won't die until the Application does, but won't keep it alive either.

You could have an Event Bus where the Listener subscribes to a known event published by the UserActivity.

*shrug* just some ideas